# Не могу запусти сервис Asp.Net Core в Debug'e на MacOs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, macos

Пытаюсь запустить свой сервис Asp.net Core на Mac'e. До этого запускал только на Винде. Сборка собирается, но затем появляется следующее сообщение:

```
Process:               dotnet [613]
Path:                  /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Identifier:            dotnet
Version:               0
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        vsdbg-ui [612]
Responsible:           dotnet [613]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-02-26 20:40:21.917 +0300
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G65)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        AFB1ADD7-536D-B727-A77B-DD3812DE4882


Time Awake Since Boot: 320 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff50ccfb66 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e9a080 pthread_kill + 333
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff50c2b1ae abort + 127
3   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ca7959 PROCAbort + 25
4   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ca78a2 PROCEndProcess(void*, unsigned int, int) + 226
5   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106f8b071 UnwindManagedExceptionPass1(PAL_SEHException&, _CONTEXT*) + 833
6   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106f8b105 DispatchManagedException(PAL_SEHException&, bool) + 133
7   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106eeec7e IL_Throw(Object*) + 750
8   ???                             0x000000010d616b01 0 + 4519455489
9   ???                             0x000000010d62b1c9 0 + 4519539145
10  ???                             0x000000010d62b14d 0 + 4519539021
11  ???                             0x000000010daa0603 0 + 4524213763
12  libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000107025c3b CallDescrWorkerInternal + 124
13  libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106e72029 MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker(unsigned long const*, unsigned long*, int) + 1657
14  libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106d39ef6 RunMain(MethodDesc*, short, int*, PtrArray**) + 726
15  libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106d3a268 Assembly::ExecuteMainMethod(PtrArray**, int) + 408
16  libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106d7a678 CorHost2::ExecuteAssembly(unsigned int, char16_t const*, int, char16_t const**, unsigned int*) + 504
17  libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106cb2052 coreclr_execute_assembly + 226
18  libhostpolicy.dylib             0x0000000106c275d7 0x106c16000 + 71127
19  libhostpolicy.dylib             0x0000000106c28438 0x106c16000 + 74808
20  libhostfxr.dylib                0x0000000106be5353 0x106bbd000 + 164691
21  libhostfxr.dylib                0x0000000106be4642 0x106bbd000 + 161346
22  libhostfxr.dylib                0x0000000106be064a 0x106bbd000 + 144970
23  dotnet                          0x0000000106ba06af 0x106b97000 + 38575
24  dotnet                          0x0000000106ba092f 0x106b97000 + 39215
25  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff50b7f015 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff50cc620a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff50cc5724 mach_msg + 60
2   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106caeb18 MachMessage::Receive(unsigned int) + 72
3   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106cada5e SEHExceptionThread(void*) + 94
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e97661 _pthread_body + 340
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e9750d _pthread_start + 377
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e96bf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff50cd109a poll + 10
1   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ca00ce CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::ThreadPrepareForShutdown() + 30
2   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ca1cc5 CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::WorkerThread(void*) + 949
3   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106cab384 CorUnix::CPalThread::ThreadEntry(void*) + 436
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e97661 _pthread_body + 340
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e9750d _pthread_start + 377
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e96bf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff50cd1142 read + 10
1   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106d229f4 TwoWayPipe::Read(void*, unsigned int) + 36
2   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106d1a549 DbgTransportSession::TransportWorker() + 2457
3   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106d186b9 DbgTransportSession::TransportWorkerStatic(void*) + 9
4   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106cab384 CorUnix::CPalThread::ThreadEntry(void*) + 436
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e97661 _pthread_body + 340
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e9750d _pthread_start + 377
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e96bf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff50ccfa16 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e98589 _pthread_cond_wait + 732
2   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106c9fdfb CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::ThreadNativeWait(CorUnix::_ThreadNativeWaitData*, unsigned int, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 347
3   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106c9fa90 CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::BlockThread(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, bool, bool, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 464
4   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ca447c CorUnix::InternalWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, void* const*, int, unsigned int, int, int) + 2028
5   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ca4762 WaitForMultipleObjectsEx + 82
6   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106d16948 DebuggerRCThread::MainLoop() + 248
7   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106d167ec DebuggerRCThread::ThreadProc() + 284
8   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106d16503 DebuggerRCThread::ThreadProcStatic(void*) + 131
9   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106cab384 CorUnix::CPalThread::ThreadEntry(void*) + 436
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e97661 _pthread_body + 340
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e9750d _pthread_start + 377
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e96bf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff50ccfa16 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e98589 _pthread_cond_wait + 732
2   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106c9fdfb CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::ThreadNativeWait(CorUnix::_ThreadNativeWaitData*, unsigned int, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 347
3   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106c9fa90 CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::BlockThread(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, bool, bool, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 464
4   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ca447c CorUnix::InternalWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, void* const*, int, unsigned int, int, int) + 2028
5   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ca3c88 WaitForSingleObject + 72
6   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106d17d9f HelperCanary::ThreadProc() + 31
7   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106d17d48 HelperCanary::ThreadProc(void*) + 56
8   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106cab384 CorUnix::CPalThread::ThreadEntry(void*) + 436
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e97661 _pthread_body + 340
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e9750d _pthread_start + 377
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e96bf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff50ccfa16 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e98589 _pthread_cond_wait + 732
2   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106c9fdfb CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::ThreadNativeWait(CorUnix::_ThreadNativeWaitData*, unsigned int, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 347
3   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106c9fa90 CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::BlockThread(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, bool, bool, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 464
4   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ca447c CorUnix::InternalWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, void* const*, int, unsigned int, int, int) + 2028
5   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ca469d WaitForSingleObjectEx + 77
6   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106f5e5e9 CLREventBase::WaitEx(unsigned int, WaitMode, PendingSync*) + 201
7   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106fa9573 SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_function() + 179
8   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106fa94b6 SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_stub(void*) + 54
9   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ec85e2 (anonymous namespace)::CreateNonSuspendableThread(void (*)(void*), void*, char16_t const*)::$_1::__invoke(void*) + 178
10  libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106cab384 CorUnix::CPalThread::ThreadEntry(void*) + 436
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e97661 _pthread_body + 340
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e9750d _pthread_start + 377
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e96bf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff50ccfa16 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e98589 _pthread_cond_wait + 732
2   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106c9fdfb CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::ThreadNativeWait(CorUnix::_ThreadNativeWaitData*, unsigned int, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 347
3   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106c9fa90 CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::BlockThread(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, bool, bool, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 464
4   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ca447c CorUnix::InternalWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, void* const*, int, unsigned int, int, int) + 2028
5   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ca469d WaitForSingleObjectEx + 77
6   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106f5e5e9 CLREventBase::WaitEx(unsigned int, WaitMode, PendingSync*) + 201
7   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106fa9541 SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_function() + 129
8   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106fa94b6 SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_stub(void*) + 54
9   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ec85e2 (anonymous namespace)::CreateNonSuspendableThread(void (*)(void*), void*, char16_t const*)::$_1::__invoke(void*) + 178
10  libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106cab384 CorUnix::CPalThread::ThreadEntry(void*) + 436
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e97661 _pthread_body + 340
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e9750d _pthread_start + 377
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e96bf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff50ccfa16 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e98589 _pthread_cond_wait + 732
2   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106c9fdfb CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::ThreadNativeWait(CorUnix::_ThreadNativeWaitData*, unsigned int, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 347
3   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106c9fa90 CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::BlockThread(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, bool, bool, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 464
4   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ca447c CorUnix::InternalWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, void* const*, int, unsigned int, int, int) + 2028
5   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ca469d WaitForSingleObjectEx + 77
6   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106f5e5e9 CLREventBase::WaitEx(unsigned int, WaitMode, PendingSync*) + 201
7   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106fa9541 SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_function() + 129
8   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106fa94b6 SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_stub(void*) + 54
9   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ec85e2 (anonymous namespace)::CreateNonSuspendableThread(void (*)(void*), void*, char16_t const*)::$_1::__invoke(void*) + 178
10  libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106cab384 CorUnix::CPalThread::ThreadEntry(void*) + 436
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e97661 _pthread_body + 340
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e9750d _pthread_start + 377
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e96bf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff50ccfa16 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e98589 _pthread_cond_wait + 732
2   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106c9fdfb CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::ThreadNativeWait(CorUnix::_ThreadNativeWaitData*, unsigned int, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 347
3   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106c9fa90 CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::BlockThread(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, bool, bool, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 464
4   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ca447c CorUnix::InternalWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, void* const*, int, unsigned int, int, int) + 2028
5   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ca469d WaitForSingleObjectEx + 77
6   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106f5e5e9 CLREventBase::WaitEx(unsigned int, WaitMode, PendingSync*) + 201
7   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106fa9541 SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_function() + 129
8   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106fa94b6 SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_stub(void*) + 54
9   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ec85e2 (anonymous namespace)::CreateNonSuspendableThread(void (*)(void*), void*, char16_t const*)::$_1::__invoke(void*) + 178
10  libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106cab384 CorUnix::CPalThread::ThreadEntry(void*) + 436
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e97661 _pthread_body + 340
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e9750d _pthread_start + 377
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e96bf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff50ccfa16 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e98589 _pthread_cond_wait + 732
2   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106c9fdfb CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::ThreadNativeWait(CorUnix::_ThreadNativeWaitData*, unsigned int, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 347
3   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106c9fa90 CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::BlockThread(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, bool, bool, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 464
4   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ca447c CorUnix::InternalWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, void* const*, int, unsigned int, int, int) + 2028
5   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ca469d WaitForSingleObjectEx + 77
6   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106f5e5e9 CLREventBase::WaitEx(unsigned int, WaitMode, PendingSync*) + 201
7   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106fa9541 SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_function() + 129
8   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106fa94b6 SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_stub(void*) + 54
9   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ec85e2 (anonymous namespace)::CreateNonSuspendableThread(void (*)(void*), void*, char16_t const*)::$_1::__invoke(void*) + 178
10  libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106cab384 CorUnix::CPalThread::ThreadEntry(void*) + 436
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e97661 _pthread_body + 340
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e9750d _pthread_start + 377
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e96bf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff50ccfa16 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e98589 _pthread_cond_wait + 732
2   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106c9fdfb CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::ThreadNativeWait(CorUnix::_ThreadNativeWaitData*, unsigned int, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 347
3   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106c9fa90 CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::BlockThread(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, bool, bool, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 464
4   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ca447c CorUnix::InternalWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, void* const*, int, unsigned int, int, int) + 2028
5   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ca469d WaitForSingleObjectEx + 77
6   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106f5e5e9 CLREventBase::WaitEx(unsigned int, WaitMode, PendingSync*) + 201
7   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106fa9541 SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_function() + 129
8   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106fa94b6 SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_stub(void*) + 54
9   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ec85e2 (anonymous namespace)::CreateNonSuspendableThread(void (*)(void*), void*, char16_t const*)::$_1::__invoke(void*) + 178
10  libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106cab384 CorUnix::CPalThread::ThreadEntry(void*) + 436
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e97661 _pthread_body + 340
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e9750d _pthread_start + 377
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e96bf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff50ccfa16 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e98589 _pthread_cond_wait + 732
2   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106c9fdfb CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::ThreadNativeWait(CorUnix::_ThreadNativeWaitData*, unsigned int, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 347
3   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106c9fa90 CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::BlockThread(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, bool, bool, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 464
4   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ca447c CorUnix::InternalWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, void* const*, int, unsigned int, int, int) + 2028
5   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ca469d WaitForSingleObjectEx + 77
6   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106f5e5e9 CLREventBase::WaitEx(unsigned int, WaitMode, PendingSync*) + 201
7   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106fa9541 SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_function() + 129
8   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106fa94b6 SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_stub(void*) + 54
9   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ec85e2 (anonymous namespace)::CreateNonSuspendableThread(void (*)(void*), void*, char16_t const*)::$_1::__invoke(void*) + 178
10  libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106cab384 CorUnix::CPalThread::ThreadEntry(void*) + 436
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e97661 _pthread_body + 340
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e9750d _pthread_start + 377
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e96bf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff50ccfa16 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e98589 _pthread_cond_wait + 732
2   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106c9fdfb CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::ThreadNativeWait(CorUnix::_ThreadNativeWaitData*, unsigned int, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 347
3   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106c9fa90 CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::BlockThread(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, bool, bool, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 464
4   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ca447c CorUnix::InternalWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, void* const*, int, unsigned int, int, int) + 2028
5   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ca469d WaitForSingleObjectEx + 77
6   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106f5e5e9 CLREventBase::WaitEx(unsigned int, WaitMode, PendingSync*) + 201
7   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106fa9541 SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_function() + 129
8   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106fa94b6 SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_stub(void*) + 54
9   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ec85e2 (anonymous namespace)::CreateNonSuspendableThread(void (*)(void*), void*, char16_t const*)::$_1::__invoke(void*) + 178
10  libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106cab384 CorUnix::CPalThread::ThreadEntry(void*) + 436
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e97661 _pthread_body + 340
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e9750d _pthread_start + 377
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e96bf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff50ccfa16 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e98589 _pthread_cond_wait + 732
2   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106c9fdfb CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::ThreadNativeWait(CorUnix::_ThreadNativeWaitData*, unsigned int, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 347
3   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106c9fa90 CorUnix::CPalSynchronizationManager::BlockThread(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, bool, bool, CorUnix::ThreadWakeupReason*, unsigned int*) + 464
4   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ca447c CorUnix::InternalWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(CorUnix::CPalThread*, unsigned int, void* const*, int, unsigned int, int, int) + 2028
5   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ca4762 WaitForMultipleObjectsEx + 82
6   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ec4d41 FinalizerThread::WaitForFinalizerEvent(CLREvent*) + 161
7   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ec4e22 FinalizerThread::FinalizerThreadWorker(void*) + 98
8   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106e32fa3 ManagedThreadBase_DispatchOuter(ManagedThreadCallState*) + 323
9   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106e335f0 ManagedThreadBase::FinalizerBase(void (*)(void*)) + 32
10  libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106ec50f8 FinalizerThread::FinalizerThreadStart(void*) + 504
11  libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106cab384 CorUnix::CPalThread::ThreadEntry(void*) + 436
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e97661 _pthread_body + 340
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e9750d _pthread_start + 377
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e96bf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff50cceece __accept + 10
1   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106d226de IpcStream::DiagnosticsIpc::Accept(void (*)(char const*, unsigned int)) const + 62
2   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106e9fd20 DiagnosticsServerThread(void*) + 288
3   libcoreclr.dylib                0x0000000106cab384 CorUnix::CPalThread::ThreadEntry(void*) + 436
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e97661 _pthread_body + 340
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e9750d _pthread_start + 377
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff50e96bf9 thread_start + 13
```

Все сообщение не вмещается. Порты и ip'шники нигде не прописывал - может в этом дело?

Comment: Исходя из написанного я бы попробовал обвернуть `Main` в `try catch`. И вывести в консоль исключение. Если  исключение не ловится, то наверно это лучше послать разработчикам.

Comment: IP-адреса и порты, здесь скорее всего не при чем. Посмотрите эту статью: https://codeblog.dotsandbrackets.com/debug-adapter-process-has-terminated/ Довольно жестко и описывает схожую проблему под Linux, но, возможно, Вы найдете что-то полезное.

Comment: @Vasek, спасибо, дело было все таки в портах- были заняты.

Comment: @SerafimProzorov, спасибо за ссылку.

Comment: @СергейТатевосян Простите, зачем Вы изменяете свой вопрос, меняя его форматирование в худшую сторону? "И да, коллеги, может хватит править мой вопрос?:D Мне так больше нравится)" — этот текст к вопросу не относится, наименования пишете неправильно.

Comment: @IgorR. окейᅠᅠᅠᅠᅠᅠᅠᅠᅠᅠᅠᅠᅠᅠᅠᅠᅠᅠ

Comment: @СергейТатевосян Задал вопрос, Ваш ответ-текст не понял, дело Ваше.

Comment: @СергейТатевосян, писать, грамотно или нет, использовать язык, как при серьезном общении или как с друзьями в баре, решать, безусловно, Вам и только Вам, но для этого же есть специальные места: Пикабу там, Лепра, это вот все. Здесь же серьезный ресурс, поэтому и хочется ASP.NET, вместо "Asp.Net" и IP-адресов, вместо "ip'шников". Такие дела.

Comment: @SerafimProzorov ваша правда, но когда правят "в Debug'e" на "в режиме отладки" - выглядит, как минимум, как неуважение к автору. В остальном согласен. Из крайности в крайность.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо в параметрах launchSettings заменить порты на свободные:

```
"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5002;http://localhost:5003"
```